# PickerView will reload by itself with wrong behavior Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, swift4.2

My pickerView was going very well, but don't know why just get wrong behavior after rebuild the project folder.

The component[0] will reload itself but I didn't write any code for it!

[image]

Below are the codes:

**DropdownListExtension.swift**

```
extension UITextField: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func loadAddressDropdownData(data: [String], zipField: UITextField!) {
        self.inputView = AddressPickerView(pickerData: data, cityField: self, zipField: zipField)

        // ToolBar
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()

        // Adding Button ToolBar
        // ...Init ToolBar
        self.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }

    @objc func doneClick() {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    @objc func cancelClick() {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

**AddressPickerView.swift**

```
class AddressPickerView : UIPickerView, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    var pickerData : [String]!
    var pickerTextField : UITextField!
    var zipTextField: UITextField!
    var selectedRow = 0
    var selectedCity = "臺北市"

    init(pickerData: [String], cityField: UITextField, zipField: UITextField) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.pickerData = pickerData
        self.pickerTextField = cityField
        self.zipTextField = zipField
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            if pickerData.count > 0 {
                self.pickerTextField.text = self.pickerData[0]
            } else {
                self.pickerTextField.text = nil
            }
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if component == 0{
            return pickerData.count
        }else {
            switch selectedCity{
            //...
            default:
                return 0
            }
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if component == 0{
            return pickerData[row]
        } else {
            switch selectedCity{
            //...
            default:
                return ""
            }

        }
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        print(component)
        if component == 0 {
            pickerTextField.text = pickerData[row]
            selectedRow = row
            selectedCity = pickerData[row]
            pickerView.reloadComponent(1)
        }else {
            switch selectedCity{
            case "臺北市":
            zipTextField.text = taipei[row]
            case "基隆市":
            zipTextField.text = keelung[row]
            //...
            default:
                return print("")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me for fix it, I spent almost 3 das but still cannot figure out the problem...

Comment: It looks like things are happening when you change component 1 - could you update your code to show what's happening in 'didSelectRow' ?

Comment: @Russell, how could I update the code? I mean 'didSelectRow' is already written on above code

Comment: ok - I thought you had commented out everything in the switch for component 1, and that there was more to show

Comment: @Russell, okay, I just update!

Comment: ok, but you have hidden a lot of other code as well - do you have any references to component[0] that you're not showing here?

Comment: @Russell, actually I show everything here, the hidden part are just switch-case for different cities :)